# Connecting to SQL Server 2008 from a Mac

Tags: sql-server, macos, jdbc, odbc

Office for Mac 2011 has better support for Pivot Tables in Excel, including external data.

I need an ODBC connection on a Mac to SQL Server 2008.  Microsoft recommends using a JDBC driver, but the documentation for it is very, very, very weak.

Here is the link to the JDBC driver: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724

Now, once that is downloaded and extracted, you can add the JDBC driver via the [Apple ODBC Administrator](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl895).

[image: JDBC Driver].

Finally, you can add the ODBC connection, but it won't let me edit the keyword or values.

[image: ODBC Connection]:

A few questions: 
Am I using the right driver/do I have it installed correctly?
Is there a way to change the keyword values in the ODBC Administrator?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to help those who stumble across this problem:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> to edit both Keyword and Value fields in Mac OS X ODBC Administrator.

Alternatively, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>

<kbd>Tab</kbd>-bing through the fields work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you found the recommendation to use a JDBC driver with MS Office 2011.  I am sure it won't work out.

However -- ODBC drivers for Mac do exist, for MS SQL Server and other DBMS, and these are fully compatible with MS Office 2011.  My employer makes [a number of these drivers](http://uda.openlinksw.com/).

For your specific need, I'd [start here](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sqlserver-st/).

Good luck!

***Edited to clarify:** All versions of Microsoft Office are built with ODBC client capabilities.  None have JDBC client capabilities.  If you're to use Microsoft Office against an JDBC driver, you'll also need an ODBC Driver for JDBC Data Sources ... such as [this one from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-jdbc-st/).*

Comment: meanwhile microsoft's jdbc driver is free